# Django refuses to connect

Tags: python, django

I created my Django website, whenever I try to go on the website, it says 127.0.0.1 is not responding. I tried troubleshooting it and it says 127.0.0.1 is refusing connection. everywhere it says that there's a firewall issue how do I fix

Comment: Did you use the port? `127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: Can you post the python manage.py runserver log please ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure because you didn't mention it, did you launch the server with the following command?

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

use this command in cmd:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

after that, you will see the IP and the port as shown in the image below

http://127.0.0.1:8000

[image: image to describe the answer]